# Read only a line from a file and split it in Python

Tags: python, file-io, split

I have an ASCII file formatted, say, like this:

```
a = 20.0
b = 30.0
c = 30.0
h3    p1   p2 p3 p4    p5
000  000  000 22 00    000
...
.
.
.
```

I only want to read the line 4 to get the names. Well, I have tried:

1) open the line, then split :

```
# Reading 'data.txt'
line = open('data.txt', 'r')
line_i = line.readlines()[3]
line.close()

line_i = line_i.split(' ')
print line_i
```

out:

```
['h3', '', '', '', 'p1', '', '', 'p2', 'p3', 'p4', '', '', '', 'p5\n']
```

2)

```
import csv
line = open('data.txt', 'r')
line_i = line.readlines()[3]
line.close()

line_i = csv.reader(line_i,delimiter=' ')
print line_i
```

out:

```
<_csv.reader object at 0x205e7c0>
```

How can this be done?

Comment: `with open('data.txt', 'r') as f: result = f.readlines()[3].split()`  Opening the file using the with-statment allows you to not worry about closing the file.  The rest is a one-liner.

Comment: I think the question is clear. This so true that we have got an answer.Also, editions have helped to enhance it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `split()`, leaving the argument blank means that consecutive whitespace will be removed:

```
>>> line = "h3    p1   p2 p3 p4    p5"
>>> line.split()
['h3', 'p1', 'p2', 'p3', 'p4', 'p5']
```

From the docs:

> If sep is not specified or is None, a different splitting algorithm is
>   applied: runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single
>   separator, and the result will contain no empty strings at the start
>   or end if the string has leading or trailing whitespace. Consequently,
>   splitting an empty string or a string consisting of just whitespace
>   with a None separator returns [].

Comment: I should have tried that before and avoiding negative hits. Thanks for the worth additional explanation